# How to compute the derivative of the following function with matrix $X$ as the variable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

The function is :$f(X)$=Trace(**1**$^{T}_{n\times m}$ $\sqrt{(AX)^2+(XB^T)^2}$)

**1**$_{n\times m}$ is a matrix with all the elements equal to 1.

$A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. 
$X$ is an $n \times m$ matrix.
$B$ is an $m \times m$ matrix

How to compute d$f(X)$/d$X$?

In $\sqrt{(AX)^2+(XB^T)^2}$, the square root and square are defined element-wise.

Comment: How the second root of a matrix is defined ($\sqrt{(AX)^2+(XB^T)^2}$)?

Comment: square and square root are defined as calculation element-wise, sorry for missing that. @K.K.McDonald

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the elementwise square-root as $S$ so that
$$\eqalign{
S\odot S &= (AX\odot AX) + (XB^T\odot XB^T) \\
}$$
and assume that its elementwise inverse $P$ exists, such that 
$\,P\odot S = {\tt1}$

Then the desired gradient is
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= A^T(AX\odot P) + (P\odot XB^T)B  \\
\\
}$$
Here is how this result was derived.

---

Let a colon denote the trace/Frobenius product, 
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
The properties of the trace allow terms in a Frobenius product to be rearranged in many ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= AC^T:B \\&= B^TA:C \\&= I:A^TBC \\
}$$
Note that the Frobenius and Hadamard products commute with themselves and each other.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A\odot B &= B\odot A \\
A:B\odot C &= A\odot B:C \\
}$$
Start by taking the differential of the square-root relation
$$\eqalign{
2S\odot dS &= 2(AX\odot A\,dX) + 2(dX\,B^T\odot XB^T) \\
}$$
Next, use these new variables to write the function.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= {\tt1}:S \\
df&= {\tt1}:dS \\
  &= (P\odot S):dS \\
  &= P:(S\odot dS) \\
  &= P:(AX\odot A\,dX) + P:(dX\,B^T\odot XB^T) \\
  &= (AX\odot P):A\,dX + (P\odot XB^T):dX\,B^T \\
  &= A^T(AX\odot P):dX + (P\odot XB^T)B:dX \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= A^T(AX\odot P) + (P\odot XB^T)B  \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask do you have a reference for proving " Frobenius and Hadamard products commute with themselves and each other"?