# Partial Derivative of Hadamard Root (elements-wise square root)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Given $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, the function is $\mathbf{f}=\sqrt{\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \odot \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}}$, where $\sqrt{(\cdot)}$ is Hadamard root (elements-wise square root), and $(\cdot) \odot (\cdot)$ is the [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). How to compute $\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}$?

---

I have tried to follow [this similar question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567157/how-to-compute-the-derivative-of-the-following-function-with-matrix-x-as-the-v) to solve my problem, but the function of that question is Frobenius inner product, which is different with mine so can not solve in that way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does the circle symbol $\odot$ mean?

Comment: It's the [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), that is the element-wise product.

Comment: That is, $f(X)$ is the element-wise absolute value of $AX$. Then this amounts basically to differentiating $|ax+b|$ w.r.t $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$\eqalign{
b &= Ax \qquad\implies\quad &db = A\,dx \\
B &= {\rm Diag}(b)  &F = {\rm Diag}(f) \\
}$$
Then calculate
$$\eqalign{
f\odot f &= b\odot b \\
2f\odot df &= 2b\odot db \\
F\,df &= B\,db = BA\;dx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= F^{-1}BA \\\\
}$$

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As it has been reckoned by Jean-Claude,
you can simplify your vector function as
$$
\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) 
= |\mathbf{Ax}|
= g(\mathbf{z})
$$
where $\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{Ax}$
and $g(\mathbf{z})=|\mathbf{z}|$.
Here the absolute value is applied
componentwise (this function is not differentiable at zero).

It follows
$$
d\mathbf{f} 
= g'(\mathbf{z}) \circ d\mathbf{z}
= g'(\mathbf{z}) \circ \mathbf{A}d\mathbf{x}
$$

The Jacobian is thus
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
=
\mathrm{diag}[g'(\mathbf{Ax})] \mathbf{A}
$$
The diagonal matrix contains -1 or +1
depending on the sign of the vector elements
$\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{Ax}$

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!